# What are possible methods for creating a physical engine

Tags: algorithm

This is a general question that comes to answer an issue that interests me for general knowledge and not to answer a specific problem.

I was wondering what are the available ways to implement a physical engine where objects interact with each other and with outside forces. As an example we can look at Angry Birds, or games like [TIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Machine_%28series%29). Where there are objects that "fly" through the air, collide and interact with each other, and are affected by the potential of the environment like gravity, winds and other "forces".

The model that I have thought about is that each object has an object (as an object of some class) and a thread that relate to it. Each time slot the thread get it "advances" the object in the space for some small dt. In this case you could have an "environment" object that can get a position in space and give you the equivalent force that is applied by the environment potential. What I can't exactly get is how the objects interact with each other?

Also, am I close in my direction? Are there other solutions and models for those problems, and are they better? What are the things I'm missing (I must be missing some things)?

Comment: The equations describing motion fall under mechanical-physics, and are incredibly simple once you understand vector-mathematics - what you described is more-or-less how game engines work.  As for "how do objects interact," it sounds like you're asking about [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection).  I'm voting to close, because this question is as broad as "How are websites made?" - there's really no way to answer without writing a book, or generalizing to such an extreme that the answer is devoid of useful content.

Comment: What I want is the generalized answer, I said that I have no practical use of the problem. And while I do understand how physics works, and how to detect collisions between two bodies. I'm interested in the mechanism that runs the collision detection procedures on all the bodies and what possible ways are there to manage it and minimize the number of operations. I guess that the main point of the question is methods for optimizing collision check procedures in a large bodies number environment.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#Optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the implementation is typically nothing like you describe, which is way too expensive.  instead, everything is reduced to matrix transformations.  points are lists of coordinates that are operated on by matrices that update them to the next time interval.  the matrices are themselves calculated from the physics (they are a linear solution of the forces at that moment, more or less).

things get more complicated when you have very large differences in scale (say, for simulating stars in a galaxy).  then you may use a more hierarchical approach so that critical (eg fast moving or, more accurately, strongly accelerating) points are updated more often than non-critical points.  but even then the in-memory representation is very abstract and nothing like as direct as "one object per thing".